# Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy using custom domain: AWS API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cors, aws-api-gateway

I have a custom domain linked to my test stage in the AWS API gateway.
I have a method as seen in the attached picture and have enabled cors (as also attached in the picture.
The endpoint will call my lambda function (with proxy lambda enabled as well)

I call the api endpoint from my Ionic angular application like so:

```
      axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
      return axios.post(url, {
        data
      }).then((response) => {

        if (response.data.status == 'success') {
      });
```

but in my console I get the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://test.mycustomendpoint.com/auth/v1/?action=login' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

I am wondering what I may be doing wrong.

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcJ4g.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcJ4g.png)
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Kr6u.png)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Kr6u.png)

Answer (score -1):

This problem only happens when you run the app using `serve` to solve it just install this chrome extension on your device from [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en)